# Partition a binary tree by removing a single edge

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, trees

The question is :

> B-3 Bisecting trees
>   Many divide-and-conquer algorithms that operate on graphs require that the graph
>   be bisected into two nearly equal-sized subgraphs, which are induced by a partition
>   of the vertices. This problem investigates bisections of trees formed by removing a
>   small number of edges. We require that whenever two vertices end up in the same
>   subtree after removing edges, then they must be in the same partition.
>
> a. Show that we can partition the vertices of any n-vertex binary tree into two
>   sets A and B, such that $|A| \leq \frac{3n}{4}$ and $|B| \leq \frac{3n}{4}$, by removing a single edge.

The proof I came up with is using induction on the number of nodes.

Assume that we can partition a tree with (n - 1) nodes in way that fulfills the requirement.  To prove we can also do it on a n nodes tree G, first remove a leaf node v from the tree and partition it, which result in 2 binary tree A' and B', which has property

$$ \frac{(n-1)}4 \leq |A'|, |B'| \leq \frac{3(n-1)}4 $$

Without loss generality, we assume that v's parent is in A'.  We put v back to A', got 2 tree, A'' and B''. If and A'' still B'' fulfill the requirement for n, then we get the partition we need.

On the other, if adding back v breaks the requirement, it means

$$ \frac{3n}4 \lt |A''| = |A'| + 1 \leq \frac{3n + 1}4  $$

Since A'' is a binary tree with less than n nodes, we can find a partition A''', B''' of A'', which has the property

$$ |A'''| \leq \frac{3}4 |A''| \leq \frac{9n + 3}{16} \leq \frac{3n}4 $$

Without loss generality, we can assume $|A'''| \geq |B'''|$, which means

$$ |A'''| \geq \frac{|A''|}2 \gt \frac{3n}{8} \gt \frac{n}4 $$

Therefore, A''' and G - A''' is a partition for G which fulfills the requirement.

---

Edit : proof of the base case.

For $ n = 1 $, the proposition doesn't apply as there no way to partition it to 2 nonempty set.

For $ n = 2 $, there's only 1 edge in the tree.  By removing this edge, we get 2 sets, A, and B which are

$$ 2 * \frac1{4} = \frac1{2} \lt |A|, |B| \lt 2 * \frac3{4} = \frac3{2} $$

So A and B is a eligible partition.  The proposition holds for base case $ n = 2 $.

---

Is my proof correct?  Any simpler proof exist?

(I Google a while but didn't find any solution for the question, so I guess it might be useful to write down my proof as it might be useful for other people.)

Comment: +1 for showing some significant thought.  You need to show the base case of n=2 (and complain that it is false for n=1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard proof is algorithmic. Root your tree arbitrarily, and execute the following algorithm. Start with the root $r$. Define a sequence $v_0 = r,v_1,\ldots$ as follows: for each $i$, $v_{i+1}$ is the child of $v_i$ with the larger subtree size (break ties arbitrarily). The sequence ends at some leaf $v_N$.

Denote by $T(v_i)$ the size of the subtree rooted at $v_i$. Since $T(v_0) = n$ and $T(v_N) = 1$, there must be some first $i$ such that $T(v_i) \geq (3/4)n$ and $T(v_{i+1}) < (3/4)n$. If $v_{i+1}$ is the only child of $v_i$ then $T(v_i) = (3/4)n$, and so disconnecting $v_i$ from its ancestor, we're done.

Otherwise, let $w$ be the other child of $v_i$. Since $T(v_i) \geq T(w)$, we have $$(3/4)n \leq T(v_i) = 1 + T(v_{i+1}) + T(w) \leq 1 + 2T(v_{i+1}).$$
Therefore for $n \geq 4$, $$n/4 \leq (3n-4)/8 \leq T(v_{i+1}) < (3/4)n,$$ and so disconnecting $v_{i+1}$ from $v_i$, we're done. If $n < 4$ then a case-analysis suffices.

Comment: Nice proof; I was thinking how to implement the $T(v_i)$. What do you think about this: 
We do DFS starting from an arbitrary root. and enumerate levels(of vertices; level(root) = 0; ...). Then start from the highest depth( highest level, i.e. leaves) and incrementally assign $T(v_i)$ values(from bottom to top). What to you think?

Comment: And something else: If we were looking for such a "vertex" I guess the same argument works. Right?

Comment: DFS should work. Once you've calculated $T(v_i)$, you can just follow the algorithm.