# Asymptotic upper bound of Bisecting trees

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

The question is :

> B-3 Bisecting trees
>
> Many divide-and-conquer algorithms that operate on graphs require that the graph
>   be bisected into two nearly equal-sized subgraphs, which are induced by a partition
>   of the vertices. This problem investigates bisections of trees formed by removing a
>   small number of edges. We require that whenever two vertices end up in the same
>   subtree after removing edges, then they must be in the same partition.
>
> c. Show that by removing at most $O(lg(n))$ edges, we can partition the vertices
>   of any n-vertex binary tree into two sets A and B such that $|A| = \lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor$ and $|B| = \lceil\frac{n}2\rceil$

I've resolved a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62194/partition-a-binary-tree-by-removing-a-single-edge), but I'm not sure if it's helpful for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Strengthen the statement to:

For any $k=1$, $\dots$, $n-1$, by removing at most $3 \lg n$ edges, we can partition the vertices of any $n$-vertex binary tree into two sets, one of which contains $k$ vertices and the other of which contains $n-k$ vertices.

The statement can then be proven by induction on $n$.  If $n=1$, the statement is vacuously true.  Otherwise, use the [previous result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62194/partition-a-binary-tree-by-removing-a-single-edge) to remove an edge to partition the tree into subtrees whose sets of vertices, $A$ and $B$, say, are such that $|A|\le 3n/4$, $|B|\le 3n/4$.  If $|A|=k$, we are done.  If $|A|>k$, use the induction hypothesis to partition $A$ into a piece of size $k$ and a piece of size $|A|-k$; otherwise, $|A|<k$, so partition $B$ into a piece of size $k-|A|$ and a piece of size $n-k$.  By the induction hypothesis, this removes at most $1+3 \lg(\frac{3}{4}n)\le 3\lg n$ edges in all.